# Can my Heroku app call a http endpoint from my GCP backend?

Tags: http, heroku, https, server, google-compute-engine

I tried deploying a Heroku web app with my Flask backend (not on Heroku, actually on GCP) and got the following message in my browser's dev console:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://x.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://x:5000/endpoint'. This request has been blocked; the content
>   must be served over HTTPS.

I have little experience with serving and SSL, but the first temptation here would be to find a way to make Heroku okay with using http endpoints. And I'd love to avoid setting up SSL if possible.

What are my options from here?

Thanks!

Comment: To which service did you deploy your heroku app? App Engine? I'm assuming (!?) that the referenced page is within the same app (because both hosts are `x`). You definitely want to (continue to) use TLS (HTTPS) but, e.g. App Engine can help with this. Assuming `x:5000` is a reference *within* the heroku app, you should drop the `http://` and the `x` (the reference should just be a relative `/endpoint`) and you should run Flask on (App Engine's preferred) port `8080` rather than `5000`.

Comment: I deployed it in Heroku. Thanks for your advice. Actually I realised that if I apply my own domain name it won't use https (unless I tell it to). So now my frontend is http, meaning my backend can stay http as well

Comment: So, you solved this issue by switching to HTTP, am I right?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza correct

Comment: Thanks! Please post it as an answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I realised that by applying my own http domain to the project (rather than using Heroku's domain), I am able to avoid the issue.

Then with http on the frontend, I was able to call http endpoints from my GCP server.